# why celery, rabbitmq needed in django-channel when it can do their job?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-channels

I was reading the documentation of **django-channels** for the first time today and found the following line `Channels will take care of scheduling them and running them all in parallel.` Does this mean, it does the celery task as well? I used to get confuse with the celery, rabbitmq, mqtt. I thought I was clear and my understanding of celery, rabbitmq and mqtt was

**celery** - background job, task scheduling

**rabbitmq** - message broker, sends message to worker

**mqtt** - it's also another message queuing

in my understanding, celery does both background job tasks as well as of rabbitmq task or mqtt task.

so my question is, when using **django-channel**, will we need to use those listed stacks(celery, rabbitmq) ? If needed, why it is needed? I look over several articles but could not get the insight clearly. I feel their usecase are somewhat similar. Can anyone clear my confusion with real life examples?